# Will my partner be allowed to live in and travel to Germany on a spouse visa while I hold a student visa?

Tags: germany, student-visa, marriage

I am Indian, registered with the city, and have a valid 6-month student visa which soon will be converted into a residence permit for 1-2 years. My partner, also Indian, works in Dubai on a residence visa with a work permit. As we look forward to spending our lives together, we have decided to marry and live together in Germany. We have already contacted the city about the legal procedures to get this done. The question is, what would our visa status be after we get married? Will my partner be allowed to live/travel here on a spouse visa while I hold a student visa? Is there anything that can be done to make this process easier?

Comment: Please clarify what kind of visa you will hold for those 1-2 years.

Comment: Student visa with a residence permit for 1-2 years

Comment: As I understand it, Familiennachzug is generally possible for students, but not easy. It requires living space, money, and health insurance for both.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But what I've heard is that family reunification is only possible if the marriage had taken place before the student visa was issued.

Comment: @NR-VA *”reunification of families of foreign students is usually only considered if the student is in possession of a residence permit, if the marriage existed at the time of said permit being granted and if the duration of the foreigner's stay in the Federal territory is expected to exceed one year. Furthermore, the student has to be able to support himself/herself and his/her family without assistance of public funds”* https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq

Comment: So does this mean that no Visa will be provided to my Fiance if we get married now?

Comment: Maybe you should change the title of the question because you are not actually asking about the marriage.

Answer (score 0):

I was myself a PhD student in Gemany when I got married. After the marriage, my wife applied for a family reunification visa.

However, you should read paragraph 30 of the immigration law - ([AufehthG 30](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__30.html)):

- Your spouse should provide a German language certificate (basic one, A1 should be enough).
- You need to have already been resident 2 years in Germany before marriage.

If you do not meet the residency requirement in Germany and are recently married, there might be problems. However, the same paragraph says that exceptions are possible (point (2)). You should ask the Ausländerbehörde and your consulate about it.

Also I would expect that your spouse will not be allowed to work without extra permission from the immigration office.